# Erro Django csv

Tags: mysql, python, django, csv

Bom, estou com um problema na leitura de csv e inserir os dados., acredito que seja na foreign key. O código é:

View:

```
def csvAih(request):
        coluna = 1
        mes = 1
        ano = 2008
        while (ano < 2017):
            with open('local', 'rb') as csvfile:
                spamreader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',', quotechar='|')
                for row in spamreader:
                    if row[0] is not None:
                        t = Aih()
                        t.idmunicipio = row[0]
                        t.quantidade = row[coluna]
                        t.data = str(ano) + '-' + str(mes) + '-01'
                        t.save(force_insert=True)
                        print t.idmunicipio, t.data, t.quantidade
            mes = mes + 1
            coluna = coluna + 1
            print mes
            if (coluna-1)%12 == 0:
                print ano
                mes = 1
                ano = ano + 1

class Municipios(models.Model):
    idmunicipio = models.IntegerField(db_column='idMunicipio', primary_key=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    nome = models.CharField(max_length=45, blank=True, null=True)
    uf = models.ForeignKey(Estados)
    latitude = models.CharField(max_length=45, blank=True, null=True)
    longitude = models.CharField(max_length=45, blank=True, null=True)
    idestado = models.IntegerField(db_column='idEstado')  # Field name made lowercase.

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'municipios'
```

Models:

```
class Aih(models.Model):
    quantidade = models.IntegerField()
    idmunicipio = models.ForeignKey(Municipios, to_field='idmunicipio',  db_column='idMunicipio')  
    data = models.DateField(primary_key=True)
```

E o erro é:

> Cannot assign "'110001'": "Aih.idmunicipio" must be a "Municipios"
>   instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O problema é que você está atribuindo o id para o atributo `idmunicipio`. No django, ele espera que você atribua uma instância, nesse caso, de `Municipios`.

Você tem duas opções, substituindo o código abaixo:

`t.idmunicipio = row[0]`

Por:

`t.idmunicipio_id = row[0]`

Ou:

`t.idmunicipio = Municipios.objects.get(pk=row[0])`

Na primeira opção você atribui diretamente o id da foreign key. Na segunda, você atribui a instância, assim como é pedido.

Comment: Amigo, funcionou...apenas colocando o `t.idmunicipio_id = row[0]`. Muito Obrigado amigo!!!! To iniciando agora com python, muitoo obrigado mesmo!

Comment: Legal, já adquiri uma certa experiência com Python. Se precisar é só falar.